# Memory limit exceeded - Apache Impala

Tags: apache, hadoop, impala

[Screenshot of my memory status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHzny.png)

Hi I'm getting a error when I try to run the TPCDS- Benchmark query

Memory Limit Exceeded by fragment: 9944e21b4d6634c0:1
  HDFS_SCAN_NODE (id=2) could not allocate 1.95 KB without exceeding limit.
Process: memory limit exceeded. Limit=256.00 MB Total=286.62 MB Peak=380.11 MB

My computer has 10GB of RAM. However impala seems to be allocated only 256MB. 
I have tried to increase memory limit on startup using mem_limit command but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: did you use `set mem_limit` prior to running your query?

Comment: I used impalad --mem_limit '1 gG' to do that. The problem seems to be the 256 mb limit on allocation as clearly seen in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem via Cloudera Manager.

Go to cloudera Manager Services > Impala > Configuration.

Under configuration search for "Memory" in the search bar. You will find the option to increase memory of impala daemon which can be setup appropriately.